# PuTTY: send over serial connection without ctrl+J

Tags: putty

I searched before asking this question but can't find similar question or helpful information.

I am trying to use PuTTY for serial communication. What is annoying is that I have to press ctrl+j if I want to send my command. I want to send my command by pressing Enter. Is that possible in PuTTY? (currently pressing Enter is interpreted as CR).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried implicit LF on CR and the reverse? ctrl-j is LF.

Comment: yes I tried it, no difference. I have to hit ctrl+j